# Getting data from MySql table with no refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have a code that counts down and when the countdown reaches 0 I want it to grab data from a MySql table and present it on the page without reloading.

I know my countdown works, but it is when I add the code to get the data from the PHP page it stops working. I know my PHP page works and grabs the correct data and presents it.

Here is the code I am currently using.

Any ideas?

```
<div id="countmesg"></div>
<div id="checking"></div>
<div id="name-data"></div>


<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var delay = 10;

    function countdown() {
        setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
        $('#countmesg').html("Auction ends in " + delay + " seconds.");
        delay--;
        if (delay < 0) {
            $('#countmesg').html("Auction ended.");
            delay = 0;
        }
    }
    countdown();
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var delay = 2;

    function countdown() {
        setTimeout(countdown, 100);
        $('#checking').html("Checking in " + delay + " seconds.");
        delay--;
        if (delay < 0) {
            $('#checking').html("Checking again....");
            var name = 'tom';
            $.post('cdown.php', {
                name: name
            }, function (data) {
                $('div#name-data').text(data);
            };
            delay = 2;
            }
        }
        countdown();
    });
</script>
```

The 3 lines that are supposed to be grabbing the PHP file are:

```
var name = 'tom';
$.post('cdown.php', {name: name}, function(data) {
    $('div#name-data').text(data);
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
require 'connect.php';

$name = 'tom';
$query = mysql_query("
                      SELECT `users`.`age`
                      FROM `users`
                      WHERE `users`.`name` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string(trim($name)) . "'"
                     );

echo (mysql_num_rows($query) !== 0) ? mysql_result($query, 0, 'age') : 'Name not found';
?>
```

Comment: Please don't use `mysql_*` functions. They're now deprecated. Check out MySQLi or PDO.

Answer (score 0):

use $.ajax instead of $.post

```
$.ajax(//url to php//).done(
    function (data) {  //data is from the php
       //do stuff
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Code you provided (3 lines):

```js
var name = 'tom';
$.post('cdown.php', {name: name}, function(data) {
    $('div#name-data').text(data);
```

It seems like you have an incomplete `$.post(...)` statement. If you check your Console you should see some Exceptions. What are they?

Update your 3 lines to this:

```js
var name = 'tom';
$.post('cdown.php', {name: name}, function(data) {
    $('div#name-data').html(data);
  });
```